# how to capture value from WebTable and send as a search criteria to a column to filter the report

Tags: java, selenium

This is related to Selenium(Java).
My requirement is:
I have a report having some columns and rows.
Columns names say is A, B, C, D ,E
Rows as {A1, B1, C1,D1, E1 ; A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 ; A3, B3, C3, D3, E3 and so on}
There is search criteria for each column
I want to capture any specific value from rows and input it in search criteria for the respective column(like A1 for A, or B2 for B like that) and click on 'Filter' button so that report is displayed with filter criteria.Like if I select value as A1 and put in search criteria for respective column A, and when I click on 'Filter' button it should show result as A1, B1, C1,D1, E1. Later I can export this report.
I need a generic code to identify/pass Webelement/value for column header, search criteria and row value of my choice(not Hardcoded). All columns, search criteria and rows are in WebTable. Can someone help. Filter button and Export to excel button is not part of WebTable.
I am using for loop to get the required column , validating column with passing value using if else but unable to pass the captured search value to search criteria.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: You can take url as "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp" . In this suppose there is some search criteria below each column(Company, Contact, Country).  You can identify column(such as Country) , enter criteria(such as UK) and then click on Filter button which is not there in WebTable but its on the page above it. Once filter is applied you can export the report to excel using export functionality. I want a generic code where I can pass column of my choice, give search criteria for that respective column.

Comment: xpath  for column can be like  //*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]/div[1] and search area for that column is //*[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]/div[2].